# How to get String from http in JSF

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I'm interested how I can get the String "Cables" from this http:

```
http://122.211.222.137:8080/test/RackProfile.jsf?id=1122#Cables
```

I use this in order to get the id:

```
this.id = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
```

But I don't know how to get the string after "#". Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The `hash` fragment of the `URL` does [**not**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4) get sent to the server, thus it's not accessible via `getRequestParameterMap`. It's typically used only by the user agent, i.e., the web browser.

A possible solution, is before submiting the form back to the server, try to modify the url, to something like the following:

```
http://122.211.222.137:8080/test/RackProfile.jsf?id=1122&type=Cables
```

Or maybe use `hidden` field to store its value, and grab it in the server.